# How to resize RichTextUploadingField in Django Page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to apply RichTextUploadingField to my front end page and the text field is extended out of the column and container that I have set.

How do I resize it to fit into the container?

Here is an image of what I mean so that it can help explain what I mean

[image]

Comment: you should probably watch for the css width and override it

Comment: @MSR974 I am trying to find the write codes to write in the CSS file. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add the CSS and HTML for the container and the RichTextUploadingField ?
It probably should be just a width, max-width missing but just checking out in details the issue